# apache griffin build fail

Tags: maven, npm

While trying to install griffin 0.6.0 on my ubuntu 22.04 machine following the guide on this link https://griffin.apache.org/docs/quickstart.html
When I run the command “ mvn clean install” I get this error:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the error, I'd suggest you try running npm install directly to see if you get a more specific error message